# Gradle implicity run another task

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have two task

```
task Hello {
   println 'Hello'
}

task World {
   println 'Hello1'
}
```

If I run `World` task `Hello`will run also. If I modify my tasks in this way

```
 task Hello {
      doLast {
          println 'Hello'
      }
    }

    task World {
       println 'Hello1'
    }
```

then task `Hello`won't run. How do `doLast{}` or `doFirst{}` sections affect running tasks in gradle?

I can't find information in gradle docs about that. Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task Hello doesn't **run**. It's **configured**.

The code inside the curly braces is the code that **configures** the task. This code is always executed, whatever the task you tell gradle to run. It must run so that gradle knows what the task does, on which other task it depends, which other task it finalizes, etc.

Once the configuration phase has finished, the execution phase starts. And in that phase, the task that you asked to execute is executed/ In that phase, the code passed to `doLast` is being executed.

Here's [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html).